# getting around multiple inheritances in C#

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I am creating a form in c# so any new form inheritances the property of build in class From
I also created a class called program which starts a connection to my Database I would like all my forms to inherit it because I don't want to open a new connection for every form
i cant use interface because program contains main() where it creates a connection
 My program class is

```
      class Program
      {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server=instance2813231.db.xeround.com;Port=18422;Database=shares info;Uid=user;Pwd=password;");
        MySqlCommand command = myConnection.CreateCommand();

        try
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("connected");


        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: You're mixing DB code with UI code. That's a big design flaw in of itself.

Comment: The question needs some improvement: Code showing us what's going on, for starters. Secondly, this is a pretty broad question because it'll get into the appropriate design of applications. I'm not sure multiple inhertiance applies here. If it does, that question has been asked a lot.

Comment: My connection isn't in my view but in UI user will be adding data to save into DB so I have to write sql INSERT statement in UI which will use my connection

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam - DB code such as INSERTs should be in a separate piece of code. For instance, in a single class that gets called by all the UI elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like all my forms to inherit it

Ick, don't. It's an abuse of inheritance in order to achieve code reuse in a very poor way.

Firstly, try to separate your GUI code from your database code.

Secondly, favour composition over inheritance - a form isn't logically a `Program` or a "database connection opener". It should *use* the latter, but it *isn't* one. You should have a single entry point, which instantiates whatever it needs to, then starts things running.

Thirdly, don't use a single connection through your code - instead, open and close connections as you need to, and let connection pooling take care of the efficiency aspect.

So instead of deriving from the class, provide each form with a reference to an instance of your database connection opener (if you *really* want to mix your database and GUI code... ick), and then your form can *use* that opener.

Comment: I have many forms connected in each one will make my application very slow is there a way around this?

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam: *What* will make your application very slow? You need to be *very* clear about what actual problem you're trying to solve - and whether you've really encountered it being a problem, or whether you're expecting it to be a problem.

Comment: I am accessing a cloud database so I open a connection every  time a new form is opened so it takes time to open the form

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam: It shouldn't - connection pooling should take care of that, if you're disposing of everything properly. You should open and close connections every time you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple inheritence, what you can do is have a `FormBase` that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and then have all your forms inherit from `FormBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiple class inheritances in C#. However, for your purpose, you can read about [connection pooling concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543.aspx)

> Connecting to a data source can be time consuming. To minimize the
>   cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an optimization technique
>   called connection pooling, which minimizes the cost of repeatedly
>   opening and closing connections. Connection pooling is handled
>   differently for the .NET Framework data providers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you're really asking the wrong question on this. The appropriate way to handle what you're asking isn't through multiple inheritance or even a FormBase. You should be considering using a [Strongly Typed DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163877.aspx), [LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc298428.aspx), or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907).

Even if you're using raw ADO.NET, you should not be hanging on to a database connection that way. Particularly if anything goes multi-threaded this will break down badly.

Don't create a connection in main, Instead use a [ConnectionString setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254494%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your app.config and open and close connections as needed where you are actually doing the work. The [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) underlying ADO.NET will take care of minimizing the expense of connection set up and tear down for you and won't get botched by multi-threading.